# How to resolve infinite recursion (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException)

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

When I call findById method from User, a result is received, however when I try to convert the return from webservice, this exception is thrown:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.empsys.user.User["locations"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.empsys.contact.details.Location["contact"]->com.empsys.user.User["locations"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.empsys.contact.details.Location["contact"]->com.empsys.user.User["locations"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.empsys.contact.details.Location["contact"]->com.empsys.user.User["locations"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.empsys.contact.details.Location["contact"] ...

The classes relationship is:

Class Contact - This class was created to represents multiple types of contacts on system.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "CONTACT_TYPE")
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="contact")
    @Column(nullable = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Location> locations;
...
```

Class User - This class was created to represent Users with specific information

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@DiscriminatorValue("USER")
public class User extends Contact {
...
```

Class Location - This class was created to represent addresses of users and others contacts of system

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCATION", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class Location implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Contact contact;
    ...
```

Dependencies used:

- (com.sun.jersey)jersey-json: version 1.18
- (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype)jackson-datatype-hibernate4: version:
  2.4.0

Could anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a pretty old post but for those who get here in the future to come, maybe you should take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue#answer-18288939).

Since Jackson 1.6 you may use [@JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences).

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues just like this. In my case I use @JsonIgnore on the properties I don't want navigated when creating the response JSON.

Comment: I need to navigate in this property, and nevertheless I've tried to use @JsonIgnore to step forward but the exception still happens.